# Access array data inside of an object (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, protected

```
    WC_Product_Attribute Object
(
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => pa_color
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26
                    [1] => 27
                    [2] => 30
                )

            [position] => 0
            [visible] => 1
            [variation] => 1
        )

)
```

How can I access values of name, options etc

Answer (score 0):

A `WC_Product_Attribute` object should have access to methods that will let you retrieve the protected data.

Say you have your `WC_Product_Attribute` stored in a variable `$attribute`.  You should be able to use methods like `$attribute->get_options()` or `$attribute->get_name()` to get the protected data.

I would recommend reviewing the WooCommerce docs for a more comprehensive list of methods you can use:

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product-Attribute.html